# Linux-Ubuntu Problem : Cannot find mysql database after connection is made to mysql

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, webapps, database

1. I have a war file deployed in webapps folder at `/srv/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/`
   War name is `InIndia.war`
2. I have deployed `inindiadb.properties` in classpath which is `/srv/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/lib`

   Contents of `inindiadb.properties`:

   jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inindia
   jdbc.username=root
   jdbc.password=admin
3. I have mysql installed and running

   ```
   netstat -vulntp |grep -i mysql
   tcp   0    0 127.0.0.1:3306    0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      563/mysqld
   ```
4. MySql Database has `inindia` database and `inindia` has 3 tables (`place`, `user_roles`, `users`)

   ```
   mysql> show databases;

   +--------------------+    
   | Database           |    
   +--------------------+    
   | information_schema |    
   | inindia            |    
   | mysql              |    
   | performance_schema |    
   | test               |    
   +--------------------+

   5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

   mysql> use inindia;
   Reading table information for completion of table and column names
   You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

   Database changed
   mysql> show tables;

   +-------------------+    
   | Tables_in_inindia |   
   +-------------------+    
   | place             |    
   | user_roles        |    
   | users             |    
   +-------------------+

   3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
5. The problem is when I restart my tomcat, a connection is made to the mysql but in tomcat logs it says that

   *catalina.out*:

   ```
   SEVERE: Error listenerStart
   Apr 18, 2014 11:02:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
   SEVERE: Context [/InIndia] startup failed due to previous errors
   ```

   *localhostlocalhost.2014-04-18.log*:

   ```
   INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
   Apr 18, 2014 10:50:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of 

   class com.inindia.listener.ApplicationInfoLoaderListener
   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM PLACE order by placeName]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'inindia.PLACE' doesn't exist
   ```

I am not able to figure out the error. The error says that `inindia.Place` cannot be found but the database as well as table is present.

It connects to the URL mentioned in `inindiadb.properties` file

I even wrote a java class to connect to the mysql server and displayed as output data of one of the tables. Connection and Data fetching both were successful.

Even I deployed the same on my local tomcat in windows which is deployed properly.Hence the war doest seem to have a problem

I am new to linux.Please let me know if there any setting to be made in mysql server.like giving previlage to database or something similar

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is an error in following line.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM PLACE order by placeName]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'inindia.PLACE' doesn't exist
```

You created table in inindia as named place, But you call it as named PLACE.

"**place**" is not "**PLACE**".

I suggest you modify "**PLACE**" to "**place**".

Comment: Hi , Its now working fine. Case thing worked. Converted my table to uppercase. Will make sure next time all my table name and the name used in code are same :)